# Catch output of keras layer

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, keras

This is my neural network :

```
model = Sequential()
act = 'relu'
model.add(Dense(430, input_shape=(3,)))
model.add(Activation(act))

model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Activation(act))
model.add(Dropout(0.42))

model.add(Dense(148))
model.add(Activation(act))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=[myAccuracy])
```

`myAccuracy` is a custom metric here
I used this command to catch the output of the final layer (Dense(1))

```
output = model.layers[8].output
print(output)
```

It gave me this output:

```
Tensor("dense_4/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
0
```

I want the output for every training example I have how do I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
predictions = model.predict(allTrainingExamples)
```